# Sobrescrever action POST de ViewSet para salvar e atualizar dados no Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Estou criando uma aplicação para controle de estoque e estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade. Quando insiro uma [entrada de produto] a quantidade de entrada deve ser somada com a quantidade em estoque de [produto]. Existe a possibilidade de fazer um update em [Produto] no método create de [entrada de produto]?

serializer de [produto]:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from produto.models import Produto


class ProdutoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Produto
        fields = ('id', 'nome', 'descricao', 'categoria', 'quantidade_estoque', 'imagem')
```

serializer de [entrada de produto]:

from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
from estoque_entrada.models import EstoqueEntrada

```
class EstoqueEntradaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EstoqueEntrada
        fields = ('id', 'produto', 'data', 'quantidade_entrada', 'valor_pago', 'usuario')
```

viewset de [entrada de produto] com o que eu tentei fazer:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from estoque_entrada.models import EstoqueEntrada
from produto.models import Produto
from produto.api.serializers import ProdutoSerializer
from .serializers import EstoqueEntradaSerializer


class EstoqueEntradaViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EstoqueEntrada.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstoqueEntradaSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        produto_queryset = Produto.objects.filter(id=request.data['produto'])
        quantidade_entrada = int(request.data['quantidade_entrada'])
        quantidade_produto = produto_queryset[0].quantidade_estoque
        quantidade_produto = quantidade_produto + quantidade_entrada
        produto_serializer = ProdutoSerializer(produto_queryset, many=True)
        produto_data = produto_serializer.data
        produto_data[0]['quantidade_estoque'] = quantidade_produto
        # produto_serializer.is_valid(produto_data)
        # produto_serializer.update(produto_data)

        entrada_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        entrada_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(entrada_serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(entrada_serializer.data)
        return Response(entrada_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Parece-me que o problema é que você está somente serializando, não [atualizando](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) a instância de `Produto` que você filtrou.

Answer (score 0):

Foi importada a classe Produto de models, obtidos e alterados seus objetos e depois utilizado o produto.save() para alteração no banco de dados.

```
from estoque_entrada.models import EstoqueEntrada
from produto.api.serializers import ProdutoSerializer
from produto.api.viewsets import ProdutoViewSet
from produto.models import Produto
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from .serializers import EstoqueEntradaSerializer


class EstoqueEntradaViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = EstoqueEntrada.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EstoqueEntradaSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        produto_queryset = Produto.objects.filter(id=request.data['produto'])
        quantidade_entrada = int(request.data['quantidade_entrada'])
        quantidade_produto = produto_queryset[0].quantidade_estoque
        quantidade_produto = quantidade_produto + quantidade_entrada
        produto_serializer = ProdutoSerializer(produto_queryset, many=True)
        produto_data = produto_serializer.data
        produto_data[0]['quantidade_estoque'] = quantidade_produto
        produto = Produto.objects.get(id=request.data['produto'])
        produto.quantidade_estoque = produto_data[0]['quantidade_estoque']
        produto.save()

        entrada_serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        entrada_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(entrada_serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(entrada_serializer.data)
        return Response(entrada_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```